Automatically Hide Rows in Google Spreadsheet Based on cell value in real-time
I am trying to create a real-time automation to hide a row as soon as the cell turns to a certain value.
I am new to Google Sheets or scripting. so far I can only get this function,
function hideRowsBasedOnCell() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i][0] == "Hide") {
      sheet.hideRows(i + 1);
    }
  }
}

I have to run it every time I want to hide the row.
Is there a way to hide the row in real time? That way, I don't have to create a button to click.

To run a script automatically when a cell value changes to a specific value, use a trigger, more specifically, an edit trigger.
There are two types of triggers: simple and installable. A simple trigger uses the reserved function name onEdit. An installable trigger could run a function; avoid setting it to run a function named onEdit, as it will be run twice.
To learn more about triggers in Google Apps Scripts, please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers and https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable.

Example of using a onEdit simple trigger with an if statement to call your function only when new cell value is certain value.
function onEdit(e){
   if(e.value === 'certain value'){
      hideRowsBasedOnCell();
   }
}

Note: As the above function uses the on-edit event Object, it should not be run from the Google Apps Script code editor by clicking the Run button because running the function this way does not create an event Object. To test the above function, you should edit a cell in your spreadsheet.
You might want to add other conditions, i.e., that the edited cell has a certain column or address.

Thank you. Please forgive me for asking; I don't quite understand. Do I need to create my function under onEdit? Is it installable? or was it separate functions?

@Steve no problem. If you will make use of a simple trigger, you might call your function from onEdit.
